# Treatment of dorsal wrist ganglia

Tags: treatment, research, wrist, ganglion-cysts, dorsal-upper-back-side

I've been researching dorsal wrist ganglion cysts and trying to find more information on treatment outcomes, both in terms of recurrence and incidence of complications.  I found a good [review article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2682407/), but unfortunately I can only see the abstracts for most of its references.

My main question:

The rates for spontaneous resolution and recurrence after treatment with aspiration both appear to be near 50% (with a pretty wide variability of reported outcomes.)  This suggests that it may be difficult to tell the difference between a ganglion that would've resolved on its own vs. one that was was only resolved due to aspiration.  Are there any studies that attempt to address this?

Related questions:

Is there any information on the reported duration of ganglion cysts in the case that they do spontaneously resolve?  I imagine this is complicated by lack of follow-up by patients when the problem goes away.

Are there any reported complications due to aspiration of dorsal ganglion cysts?  I found a reference to a 5% complication rate in a referenced article from the survey ([abstract here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12631492)), but this was for palmar ganglia.  Lacking more specific data, are there known complications for aspiration procedures in general?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here. What are you asking?

Comment: There are a few questions, which I'm hoping are sufficiently related to warrant a single response.  Do you think the question would work better if focused on one of the three questions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't fully read your bullet points. Yes, one item per question is the expected format.